# Manipulate fails with f[x]=x^k/(1+x^k)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

I have this code:

```
Clear[f]
f = Function[x, x^k/(1 + x^k)];
Manipulate[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}], {k, 1, 10}]
```

But nothing draws as I move the slider.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

`Manipulate` has the attribute `HoldAll` and therefore `f` is **not** evaluated to your function. Therefore the expression with `k` is not visible for `Manipulate`.

```
Clear[f]
f = Function[x, x^k/(1 + x^k)];
With[{f = f},
 Manipulate[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}], {k, 1, 10}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to know, why `With` is one possible solution, you could check the following thread:

[What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/187)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Clear[f]
f = Function[{x, k}, x^k/(1 + x^k)];
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, k], {x, 0, 5}], {k, 1, 10}]
```

To see what is happening, do

```
Clear[f]
f = Function[{x, k}, x^k/(1 + x^k)];
Manipulate[f[x, k], {k, 1, 10}]
```

and

```
Clear[g]
g = Function[x, x^k/(1 + x^k)];
Manipulate[g[x], {k, 1, 10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `Replace` within the `Manipulate`

```
Clear[f]
f = Function[x, x^k/(1 + x^k)];
Manipulate[Plot[f[x] /. k -> k1, {x, 0, 5}], {k1, 1, 10}]
```